# Javadoc and custom doclet

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, documentation, javadoc

I'm trying to generate documentation of an android project using javadoc from commandline to use a custom doclet and generate a PDF file.

I'm using AurigaDoclet.

Here is the command, but it doen't find any source file:

javadoc -doclet com.aurigalogic.doclet.core.Doclet -docletpath "C:\Program Files\Java\aurigadoclet\bin\AurigaDoclet.jar" -format pdf -sourcepath "E:\Projects\MobileApp\src*.java" -package it org -out "E:\DemoDoc.pdf"

it and org are packages of the mobile app, but javadoc says that packages it and org do not contain any source files.

Should I specify the full path to each file of the project??
like this "it.company.x.y.java"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question while looking for an answer. I might have found one and want to share it. The following command worked for me.

```
javadoc -doclet com.aurigalogic.doclet.core.Doclet -docletpath C:\PATH\AurigaDoclet.jar -format pdf -out D:\demo.pdf -sourcepath C:\projectFolder\projectName\src -subpackages mainPackage
```

In my case i've got a package structure like this

```
mainPackage\a
mainPackage\a\b
mainPackage\d
```

and the -subpackage command seems to go recursive through the content of the mainPackage